# Generic PCL 5 printer prints garbage on first page

Tags: drivers, raspbian, cups, printer

I have an RPi hooked up to my Dell 1720 printer, with a Generic PCL 5 Printer - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9 driver running the thing. When I go to print, nine times out of ten the first page is garbage. It looks like it's printing the first six lines of the page, blown up to cover the whole height of the page.

Is this something anyone else has experienced? Any advice?

Comment: have you checked the logs, something like `/var/log/cups/`

Comment: nothing unusual in the error, access, or page logs.